# Python class to open and close website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, class

Trying to setup `Chrome` for the `open / close` a website. Now i can open it, But failed to close it.

Can anyone tell me why? Many thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class chromeSetup():
    def __init__(self):
        self.chrome_path    = r'C:\XXXXX\chromedriver.exe'

    def searchWeb(self, url="https://www.google.com.hk/"):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chrome_path)
        driver.get(url)

    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: ‘fail to close’ Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: what's is the error code ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 14, in close
AttributeError: 'chrome' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: The error showed when I ran XXX.close()

Comment: call `chromeSetup().close()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not making `driver` an instance attribute. Change `searchWeb` method like this:

```
def searchWeb(self, url="https://www.google.com.hk/"):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chrome_path)
    self.driver.get(url)
```